# Slow bash script to execute sed expression on each line of an input file

Tags: bash, parsing, sed, fasta

I have a simple bash script as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
#This script reads a file of row identifiers separated by new lines 
# and outputs all query FASTA sequences whose headers contain that identifier.
# usage filter_fasta_on_ids.sh fasta_to_filter.fa < seq_ids.txt; > filtered.fa


while read SEQID; do
    sed -n -e "/$SEQID/,/>/ p" $1 | head -n -1
done
```

A fasta file has the following format:

```
> HeadER23217;count=1342
ACTGTGCCCCGTGTAA
CGTTTGTCCACATACC
>ANotherName;count=3221
GGGTACAGACCTACAC
CAACTAGGGGACCAAT
```

**edit** changed header names to better show their actual structure in the files

The script I made above does filter the file correctly, but it is very slow. My input file has ~ 20,000,000 lines containing ~ 4,000,000 sequences, and I have a list of 80,000 headers that I want to filter on. Is there a faster way to do this using bash/sed or other tools (like python or perl?) Any ideas why the script above is taking hours to complete?

Comment: I would parse the file and put it into a database. While the import process takes it's time, once it has been imported, queries can be very fast.

Comment: @hek2mgl: A database takes up linear space and/or memory. If you have many queries, it's more straightforward and/or efficient to do a linear scan. See my answer

Comment: Why run `sed` once per input, rather than doing a single scan that matches any of the sequences you care about? `sed` is a Turing-complete scripting language, after all -- there's quite a lot that can be done with it, this included.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yes, it has been proved that `sed` is Turing complete, but seriously ... ! ;)

Comment: This is an example of me getting something to work for one sequence, but not understanding the overhead it would take to scale. The answers below do a great job of scaling better when I increase queries.

Comment: If you want something nice, use a database, use hadoop(!) ... `sed` will never scale like that. I mean you do proper research (I assume) why using poor tools for analyzing the results?

Comment: @elsherbini: What you do is scan the 4M sequences file (~350 megabytes for me) once *per header*, i.e., 80k times. That makes 28 gigabytes scanned. Costly! Instead one should try to limit to a single scan of both files.

Comment: @JoSo A Linux (file) system (and I guess others as well) will keep the file in memory buffers if it is accessed that frequently. That's not the deal. But still it is required to iterate over the file for each header.

Comment: @hek2mgl: you're totally right (as long as it fits in memory). I removed the "disk" thing.

Comment: And it's not 28 gigabytes, but 28 *terabytes*. But can't edit anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're scanning the large file 80k times.  I'll suggest a different approach with a different tool: `awk`.  Load the selection list into an hashmap (awk array) and while scanning the large file if any sequence matches print.

For example

```
$ awk -F"\n" -v RS=">" 'NR==FNR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a["Sequence ID " $i]; next}
                        $1 in a' headers fasta
```

The `-F"\n"` flag sets the `field separator` in the input file to be a new line. `-v RS=">"` sets the record separator to be a `">"`

```
Sequence ID 1
ACTGTGCCCCGTGTAA
CGTTTGTCCACATACC

Sequence ID 4
GGGTACAGACCTACAT
CAACTAGGGGACCAAT
```

the headers file contains

```
$ cat headers
1
4
```

and the fasta file includes some more records in the same format.

If your headers already includes the "Sequence ID" prefix, adjust the code as such.  I didn't test this for large files but should be dramatically faster than your code as long as you don't have memory restrictions to hold 80K size array.  In that case, splitting the headers to multiple sections and combining the results should be trivial.

To allow any format of header and to have the resulting file be a valid FASTA file, you can use the following command:

```
awk -F"\n" -v RS=">" -v ORS=">" -v OFS="\n" 'NR==FNR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[$i]; next} $1 in a' headers fasta > out
```

The `ORS` and `OFS` flags set the output field and record separators, in this case to be the same as the input fasta file.

Comment: thanks, by loading the file into memory and using awk this operation took less than a few minutes, rather than over four hours. It'd be helpful if the awk script could be broken down so I could make some changes (basically I want a valid fasta file as output, with '>' in front of headers and no blank lines).

Answer (score 0):

You should take advantage of the fact (which you haven't explicitly stated, but I assume) that the huge fasta file contains the sequences in order (sorted by ID).

I'm also assuming the headers file is sorted by ID. If it isn't, make it so - sorting 80k integers is not costly.

When both are sorted it boils down to a single simultaneous linear scan through both files. And since it runs in constant memory it can work with any size unlike the other awk example. I give an example in python since I'm not comfortable with manual iteration in awk.

```
import sys

fneedles = open(sys.argv[1])
fhaystack = open(sys.argv[2])

def get_next_id():
    while True:
        line = next(fhaystack)
        if line.startswith(">Sequence ID "):
            return int(line[len(">Sequence ID "):])

def get_next_needle():
    return int(next(fneedles))

try:
    i = get_next_id()
    j = get_next_needle()
    while True:
        if i == j:
            print(i)
        while i <= j:
            i = get_next_id()
        while i > j:
            j = get_next_needle()
except StopIteration:
    pass
```

Sure it's a bit verbose, but it finds 80k of 4M sequences (339M of input) in about 10 seconds on my old machine. (It could also be rewritten in awk which would probably be much faster). I created the fasta file this way:

```
for i in range(4000000):
    print(">Sequence ID {}".format(i))
    print("ACTGTGCCCCGTGTAA")
    print("ACTGTGCCCCGTGTAA")
    print("ACTGTGCCCCGTGTAA")
    print("ACTGTGCCCCGTGTAA")
```

And the headers ("needles") this way:

```
import random

ids = list(range(4000000))
random.shuffle(ids)
ids = ids[:80000]
ids.sort()
for i in ids:
    print(i)
```

Comment: The sequences are sorted, but not alphabetically. This would also be a good approach if I made sure the query file was sorted the same way.

Comment: I don't assume that they are sorted alphabetically. I assume they are sorted *numerically*, by ID.

Comment: (Or more generally, the requirement is that they are sorted in the same way)

Answer (score 0):

It's slow because you are reading several times the same file when you could have sed read it once and process all patterns. So you need to generate a sed script with a statement for each ID and the `/>/b` to replace your `head -n -1`.

```
while read ID; do
    printf '/%s/,/>/ { />/b; p }\n' $ID;
done | sed -n -f - data.fa
```